# getting "browser.getTabIds" is not a function in webdriverio while calling browser.getTabIds()

Tags: webdriver-io

getting error "browser.getTabIds" is not a function in webdriverio version-6, while calling browser.getTabIds()

Answer (score 1):

There is no such command, I guess https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver.html#getwindowhandles is what you trying to achieve.